# Why is my sorting method not swapping after the second iteration of the for loop? (Java Helsinki MOOC PART 7-3)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Working on part 5 of exercise 7-3 of https://java-programming.mooc.fi/part-7/2-algorithms

I can't figure out why I can't get the array to print from least to greatest. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

My sorting Method:

```
public static void sort(int[] array) {
    for (int i =0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[indexOfSmallestFrom(array,i)]) {
            swap(array, i, indexOfSmallestFrom(array, i));
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}
```

My swap method:

```
public static void swap(int[] array, int index1, int index2) {
    int oldint1 = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = oldint1;
}
```

And my indexOfSmallestFrom method:

```
public static int indexOfSmallestFrom(int[] table, int startIndex) {
    int minValue = table[0]; //keeps running count of the smallest value
    int minIdx = 0; //will store the index of minVal

    for (int index = 1 ; index < table.length; index++) {
        if (table[index] < minValue) {
            minValue = table[index];
            minIdx = index;
        }
    }

    return minIdx;
}
```

Here is the original array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your test code here
    int[] numbers = {8, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 4};
    MainProgram.sort(numbers);
}
```

Trying to the get sort method to print from least to greatest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `indexOfSmallestFrom` method isn't using the `startIndex` argument - it always searches from 0. If you correct this:

```
public static int indexOfSmallestFrom(int[] table, int startIndex) {

    int minValue = table[startIndex]; //keeps running count of the smallest value
    int minIdx = startIndex; //will store the index of minVal
    for (int index = startIndex + 1; index < table.length; index++) {
        if (table[index] < minValue) {
            minValue = table[index];
            minIdx = index;
        }
    }

    return minIdx;
}
```

then the sorting works and it eventually arrives at an ordered list:

```
[1, 3, 7, 9, 8, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 7, 9, 8, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That definitely did the trick. Appreciate you jon.

Comment: NP. Can you accept the answer (i.e. click the tick icon next to it).